# MVC Session timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am new to MVC. Am redirects page to login page at the time of sessionout. But i am getting below error when i copy the URL from one browser to another browser.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\sathish\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\citrusz\c8f40333\adcdafd9\App_Web_vbginoqd.3.cs:0
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88
System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233
System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I have used following class for session timeout handling

```
 public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("/Login/Logout");
                }
            }
        }


        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This is my part of _layout.cshtml page.

```
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <img class="nav-user-photo" src="@Session["FlagURL"].ToString()" alt="Jason's Photo" />
                        <span class="user-info">
                            <small>Welcome,</small>
                            @Session["Name"].ToString()
                        </span>

                        <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Exception text points to your `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file, can you provide it's code?

Comment: @berrunder: I ve shared my layout page. Please help

Comment: @Session["Name"].ToString() This will cause exception. Put a null check before.

Comment: Looks to me you have to handle the case when your `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null` and redirect if so. Bug in the  `SessionExpireFilterAttribute` class.

Answer (score 1):

Put your session logic in this event of global.asax,

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your code whether session got expired or not.
}
```